# Add new property to the default User class in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and I am developing an app where I want to have Users with custom properties.
I would like to use the default User class since it has methods and properties I need.
But I don't how to add new properties (for example; City).

The sign-up is currently working and I am adding the information to CloudFirestore in this way:

```
Future<void> addUser(User user){
    //create a CollectionReference to add a new user
    CollectionReference usersCollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    return usersCollectionReference.doc(user.uid)
        .set({
      'user_uid':user.uid,
      'email':user.email,
    })
        .then((value) => print('user added to cloud firestore'))
        .catchError((onError) => print('Failed to add user to cloud Firestore: $onError'));

  }
```

So, my question is how could I custom properties to that user?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean new properties? The `User` class is a third party class...

Comment: There is no default user class in Flutter. Do you maybe mean Firestore?

Comment: this class is inside the firestore package

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant User class of Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a parent `class`, that contains all the desired properties, and the reference to the `User` instance:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Account {
  User user;
  String city;
  Account({this.user, this.city}); // example constructor
}
```

By doing so, it's possible to access both the `User` `class` functionality, and all the additional properties/functions defined in the `Account` `class`:

```
Account account = new Account(user: user, city: 'Washington');
print(account.user.displayName);
print(account.city);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Didn't think about this option. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help! Please don’t forget to select the answer as correct